# Rotate objects in WPF ZAM 3D

Tags: wpf, 3d

How do I rotate a 3D object which are created from ZAM 3D tool in XAML, I have created some objects by using ZAM 3D, here we can rotate objects in Trackball or in Camera mode, but it does not works in XAML. Can u please suggest me how can i achieve the same thing in XAML portion? it will be much appreciated.

In brief, 
1. How to export multiple camera views from ZAM 3D to XAML
(or)
2. How to use camera view from mouse pointer

Regards,Raijan_cv

Comment: You state "it does not works in XAML". What have you tried? What did it do or not do?

Comment: means, i cant able to see different view of an object in XAML, which can in ZAM 3D by roation trackball or camera mode.

Comment: You might look at the Helix Toolkit (http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com) which gives you great WPF 3D viewer controls.